# Bigquery data not getting uploaded

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-bigquery

my job id is  job_7mb6iw3BHoMRC09US9Vqq-Qd06s, while uploading data by this job on Bigquery  The data was not getting uploaded on bigquery. And I am not getting any error for this.

Answer (score 1):

That job failed with reason "invalid" and message starting with "Too many errors encountered."

In order to detect job failure, when you get a successful response from jobs.get, first ensure that the job is in a DONE state, then look for the presence of errors in the `status.errorResult.reason` and `status.errorResult.message`. Additionally, the `status.errorStream` will contain a list of individual failures encountered. In this case, it looks like the job was trying to load data that didn't match the schema of the table. You can find the file/line/field offsets in the "location" field of each error in the errorStream.

Here are a couple of causes for "not finding the errors in the job" that we've seen:

- Forgetting to check for DONE before looking for job errors.
- Waiting for job completion with a timeout, but forgetting to treat timeout as failure.
- Letting temporary errors from jobs.get (5xx http response codes) terminate your wait loop early, and then not knowing the state of the job since the jobs.get itself failed.

I hope this helps narrow down the problem for you.